# Rails ransack search condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, ransack

Is there a way to add a "condition" to a ransack search? I want to search through published Articles only.

Currently my code looks like this and is working perfectly. But it shows articles that are not yet published, too.

```rb
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = 'name asc' if @q.sorts.empty?
    @article = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:vendor,
                                               :description,
                                               :alt_art_names,
                                               :alt_vendor_names,
                                               :certificates,
                                               :article_reports,
                                               :article_ratings,
                                               :article_community_ratings)
```

Is there a way to add something like "where('article.published_at <= ?', Time.now)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```rb
 @q = Article.where("articles.published_at <= ?", Time.now).ransack(params[:q])
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, too. But when I want to search something, I'm getting an Error: `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "published_at" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...= "article_community_ratings"."explanation_id" WHERE (published_... ^`

Comment: UPDATE: I missed, that you added "**articles**.published_at" to it. That really did it. Thank you so much!